# How can I tell if $addToSet actually pushed anything?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I would like to tell whether or not $addToSet found a duplicate or not while updating the Mongo database. Is there a way to tell whether the new data was pushed and added?

```
Watchlist.findByIdAndUpdate(list.id, { $addToSet: { watchlist: req.body.stockAdded } }, { new: true }, function (err, tank) {
    if (err) return handleError(err);
    res.status(200).send({ "success": "Updated Successfully", "status": 200 });
});
```

Comment: I don't think you can do that with the native MongoDB operators but you can use a utility library like [lodash](https://lodash.com/) in the callback and use its [`_.difference()`](https://lodash.com/docs#difference) method but on the original unmodified document: `_.difference(tank.watchlist, [req.body.stockAdded])`

Comment: ill check this out thanks

Comment: Possible dupe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22971821/how-to-determine-if-addtoset-actually-added-a-new-item-into-a-mongodb-document